# Pandas.DataFrame: How to transform from 'multiple value' column to 'a value column and type' column?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, pandas-groupby

I have a question about pandas.DataFrame. I have a DataFrame(let's name it **df**) as below.

[from here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LysWj.png)

I want to transform this df to a DataFrame as below.

[To here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FDush.jpg)

Comment: You want [stack](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.stack.html) and [reset_index](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.reset_index.html).

Comment: df.stack(0).reset_index() worked very well. Thanks!

Comment: while the question has been answered, since this is your first (?) post, going forward can you please put the code into your question as text not as images. It makes it easier for other people to reproduce/understand your problem and answer your question quicker.